# Change the height and width of text area

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I need to change the width and the height of the `<textarea>` tag of HTML and I need it to have just
two lines (rows). Currently, it has just one line. Any idea how to fix this?

For the width, even if I change it to `1000px` nothing changed and I don't understand why.

```
<div>
    <textarea rows="2" cols="200" disabled="disabled" style="width:500px; height: 10px;">
        Date
        User 
    </textarea>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap in an MVC5 application.

Comment: Are you sure that two lines, each up to 200 characters, are the right approach. Instead of a two-liner `textarea`, two `input` elements might be better. And setting height to a value smaller than normal font size can be *expected* to make the area just one line tall.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove the height declaration on the `textarea`, just specify the rows using `rows="2"`

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="200" disabled="disabled" style="width:500px;">
Date
User 
</textarea>
```

`height` will conflict with `rows` and `width` will conflict with `cols`.

Comment: In that case, please post your full code as you have something conflicting with it.

In this JSFiddle you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/6npu7/1/

Comment: -thanks I found some conflict in the code for the hight but for width I didn't found why I cannot give it more than cols=200,what can cause to this,any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Keep reading if you want to set height of your text areas depending on size of 
 the content

```
<textarea  id ="code" rows="2" cols="200" disabled="disabled" style="width:100%; height:auto"  >
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>

    </body>
    </html>

    </textarea>
```

And then in Document ready assign height of text area = scroll size

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  textAreaAdjust(document.getElementById('code') );
});

function textAreaAdjust(o) {
  o.style.height = "1px";
  o.style.height = (o.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this :

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="200" disabled="disabled" style="width:500px !important;height:250px !important;">
Date
User 
</textarea>
```

**PS :** replace height:250px by the height you want

Comment: You should not override styles using `!important` when it can be easily dictated via `rows` or `cols` or by simply removing them.

Comment: but you cant remove the styles added by the browser