# How to align textarea height with next input element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set some input design in my sample app. inside it , I have input and textareas. from perspective view,our requirement is to set height aligned with input element.

I would like to align height of textare with input element close to it.When I simply set them as follows. it distorted.

```html
<div>
  <input value="input test">
  <textarea>textarea test</textarea>
</div>
```

My desired result is like follows. the height of textare is aligned with input element. How can I achieve this ?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why would you want a textarea that has a appearance, alignment and function as a `input`. What are you trying to achieve specificly?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994395/change-the-height-and-width-of-text-area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994395/change-the-height-and-width-of-text-area) maybe this link can help you

Comment: use this css : textarea,
  input {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 20px
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can start by doing this:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
  .wrapper > input {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input value="input test">
  <textarea>textarea test</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: start;">
  <input value="input test">
  <textarea>textarea test</textarea>
</div>
```

The form-group div container has the display: flex and align-items: stretch properties, which align the heights of the child elements. The textarea element has the height: 100% property

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <input value="input test">
  <textarea>textarea test</textarea>
</div>
```